# Angular js performance issue in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to render a large number of records let say `8000` on UI

my HTML code is

```
<ul id="ul{{group.Id}}">
 <li data-ng-repeat="vehicle in group.Vehicles | filter:VehRegNo">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" data-ng-disabled="IsAllLoading" data-ng-model="vehicle.IsChecked" data-ng-change="changeCheck(vehicle)">
 </li>
</ul>
```

On controller side

```
group.Vehicles = getDataGradually(items, 0, 50, function() {
    $scope.$digest();
}, function() {
    $scope.IsAllLoading = false;
    $("#cb" + id).toggle();
    $("#lbl" + id).toggle();
});
//if i put all items dirctly to vehicles then ui freez

function getDataGradually(data, gap, count, updateCb, finishCb) {
    var ret = [];
    var handled = 0;

    function doInsert() {
        var start = handled;
        var end;
        if (handled + count > data.length) {
            end = data.length;
        } else {
            end = handled + count;
        }
        for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret[i] = data[i];
        }
        handled += count;
        if (handled < data.length) {
            $timeout(function() {
                doInsert();
                updateCb && updateCb();
            }, gap);
        } else {
            return finishCb && finishCb();
        }
    }
    doInsert();
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is it is taking huge time; sometimes 2 to 3 minutes to render all items.Is there any suggestion paging is not an option for the client also there is some search filter also.

Comment: add `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` in app config for more https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider

Comment: Precompute the filtered list in your controller so you can control when it is rebuilt. In your html it is probably recomputing the list on every digest loop.

Comment: If the issue is the amount of data being displayed you could try something like https://github.com/klajd/angular-virtual-repeat

Comment: Try out $("*").length in the console, this will give you a good idea about whether you are choking your browser with too much DOM elements or it boils down to the calculations per cycle

Comment: Also you may want to consider `track by $index` if it's not a problem for your specific situation.

Comment: try to use ONE-TIME BINDINGS  https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Comment: @nmanikiran if i do one time bind then this will stop after first digest cycle in my method

Comment: @Lys $("*").length gives me 56000

Comment: @jitender not for every property add where ever is possible and try `$compileProvider`

Comment: @nmanikiran i already tried it but no success :-)

Comment: @jitender that in my experience is quite a bit, especially for some browsers. I'd suggest except all other optimizations regarding calculations per cycle that you come up with some kind of pagination or infinite scroll / lazy loading. I am currently tackling a similar problem in Angular 2. The performance might be a huge issue especially if in a loop you create other ng components / directives.

Comment: @jitender another thing - if you use two way binding Angular is applying change detection algorithm over the tree of elements and this could be troublesome for performance.

Comment: I vote for @Duncan's comment, filter the list in the controller instead of using the filter in the template, the filter fires with every digest loop. Also, as you have to many elements, remove the `ng-model` directive and take leverage of the  `ng-change="changeCheck(vehicle)`

Comment: @CastroRoy Ducans thanks,I will try to filter in controller lets see what happen